# Scraping new price with python

Tags: python, html, list, join, web-scraping

I have been creating a code that will automatically get me all needed information for listed houses in my area, and then prints it to a .CSV file for me to check.

Its works fine all but on part where there is new price following old price.

When it works:

```
<h6><span>Hinta</span></h6><span>97 500 €</span>
```

When it does not work:

```
<h6><span>Hinta</span></h6><span>299 000 €</span><span class="styles__priceIcon__3aKp_"><span aria- 
label="" class="material-icons" data-react-toolbox="font-icon">arrow_downward</span></span><span 
class="styles__previousPrice__3EHyA">329 000 €</span>
```

By this I get prize for all others(where list is only two numbers long):

```py
prize_number_list = re.findall("\d+", prize_line) =====>  ['299', '000', '329', '000']

prize = ''.join(prize_number_list)  ========> 299000329000
```

How can I separate first two numbers from the list, and combine them to one number like this 299000?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by only joining the first two items of the list,

```py
prize_number_list = ['299', '000', '329', '000']

prize = ''.join(prize_number_list[:2])

print(prize)
```

Comment: Well that was simple... Thank you very much :)

Comment: @JoonaVeteläinen No problem, please consider marking my answer as accepted and up voting for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

```
price_list = ['299', '000', '329', '000','429','000']

for i in zip(price_list[::2],price_list[1::2]):
    print(i[0]+i[1])
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation on how this works. The OP doesn't mention any cases where there would be three numbers.